# NuGet install tools package in Docker Apline

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, alpine-linux

I am trying to install a NuGet tools package inside an Alpine Docker container.

In Windows I would do the following -

```
nuget install SomeToolPackage
```

Doing so would result in a new set of directories like -

```
tools\netcoreapp2.1\SomeTool.dll
tools\netcoreapp2.1\* many other files
```

**Question**

What is the equivalent in for Linux. I am aware that some people are using Mono to run the Windows `nuget.exe` file.

I can also use `wget` and `unzip`.

I hope there is a better way using the tools from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The path going forward is to use [dotnet tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install) (see also [dotnet core global tools overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools) and [creating a global tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create)). However, it's not a 1:1 mapping with `nuget.exe install`, as the package must be authored as a tool, whereas `nuget install` allows you to "install" any package.